# Extension library and JDBC driver

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

For xPages extension library ver. 853 I'm using "Extlib_8.5.3_DB2_Driver_updateSite201110201044.zip"  JDBC driver..
But now I'm gonna switch to Domino 9. So I'm gonna use Extension Library ver 901. Where can I download appropriate DB2 JDBC driver from for that version? Or should I still use the one that is for 853?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 9.0.1 Extension Library has a tool that gets installed that lets you build a plugin from any JDBC driver. You can download the desired DB2 JDBC driver from IBM and then build the plugin. This tool is accessed from Designer using the Tools menu, JDBC Driver Plug-in Wizard.